# How does InheritableThreadLocal work for instance variable thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I have the following program

```
class ParentThread extends Thread{

    public ParentThread(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    static InheritableThreadLocal tl = new InheritableThreadLocal();
    ChildThread c = new ChildThread("child");

    @Override
    public void run() {
        tl.set("pp");
        System.out.println("Thread :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" thread local value: "+tl.get());
        c.start();
    }
}
class ChildThread extends Thread{
    public ChildThread(String child) {
        super(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" thread local value: "+ParentThread.tl.get());
    }
}
public class ThreadLocalDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ParentThread p = new ParentThread("parent");
        p.start();
    }
}
```

I get the output as

```
Thread :parent thread local value: pp
Thread :child thread local value: null
```

I believe that even though I declared ChildThread as an instance variable, the parent thread run method is responsible for creating the child thread. So, why would the output be null for the child?

When I put this

```
ChildThread c = new ChildThread("child");
```

inside the run method, I do get pp. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API docs:

> when a child thread is created, the child receives initial values for
> all inheritable thread-local variables for which the parent has
> values.

Let's rewrite `ParentThread` to be more explicit without changing any implementation. (There is no particular reason to have `ParentThread` in the demo at all - the main thread would do just fine. **Edit: I should have continued this thought. The `ChildThread` instance inherits inheritable thread locals from the *main thread*, not the `ParentThread` instance.**)

```
class ParentThread extends Thread{
    static InheritableThreadLocal tl;
    static {
        tl = new InheritableThreadLocal();
    }

    /* pp */ ChildThread c;

    public ParentThread(String s) {
        super(s);
        this.c = new ChildThread("child");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        tl.set("pp");
        System.out.println("Thread :"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" thread local value: "+tl.get());
        c.start();
    }
}
```

There we see the `ChildThread` constructor is being called before `InheritableThreadLocal.set`. Write `new ChildThread()` after `tl.set(pp);` and the value should be seen.

`InheritableThreadLocal` is nuts. I'd avoid it unless doing something malicious.

In general I strongly suggest avoiding subclassing without necessity and `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: I'm confused because just like you said, in the API docs, it says "when a child thread is created, the child receives initial values...", but a child thread is only created when we execute child.start(), & before that I've already set "pp"

Comment: When the `Thread` object is created. `start` merely begins execution of an existing thread.